# Moving content from one site to another - keep content on both sites

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, content

I have 1 domain with about 100 posts

**I would like to move those 100 posts to another (new) domain BUT also keep the posts on the existing (old) domain!**

Would copying the content to the new domain, while adding a link in each of the posts in the existing content which resides on the old domain to the new domain, be sufficient to credit the new domain with the "old" content which resides on the "old" domain

**So to recap:** I would like to credit my new domain with the content of my old domain while keeping content on both domains but crediting the new domain with the content.

- Would linking from old domain to new domain in each post be
  sufficient to credit the new domain?
- What would be the best way to go about this?

Hope this makes sense, please feel free to ask if any questions if question is unclear

Comment: I'd take closetnoc's advice and maybe add text on the new domain that briefly mentions where the posts originated from, that way you'll give the posts credit.

Answer (score 5):

If you have inbound (back) links to your old pages, these may always come up first in search. However, other than that, the rest is easy.

You can copy your content to your new domain. From your old domain, create a canonical link on your pages pointing to your new pages.

That is it!

Here is the Google page regarding canonical links:

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en

Look for the header:

Indicate the preferred URL with the rel="canonical" link element

Use the example found. Keep in mind that you are putting these on the pages of the old domain. You can also put them on the new domain and that may help too. As long as the URL you use on both domains point to the new domain.